# Possible to Toggle Next/End Button in CodenameOne on Android VKB

Tags: java, android, codenameone

When I create a TextField in CodenameOne I want to be able to have the keyboard give the user the option to be done with the textfield, however in Android the button is always showing up as next. If the user clicks next it takes them to a textfield that doesn't make sense for it to be going to for my application. Even if I could trigger the next button to just close the textfield, that would work.

This is how I'm generating the textfield:

TextField test = new TextField("", "", 20, TextArea.NUMERIC);

Answer (score 1):

It seems that adding a done listener does the trick:

```
test.setDoneListener((ee) -> {
    test.stopEditing();
});
```

Comment: See `getTabIterator` (in `Form`) to determine the next focus component and explicitly determine the next component in the focus order. In Android "Done" is unnecessary since the physical back button folds the keyboard.

Comment: Dear Shai, in my opinion the "Done" button is necessary also in Android, because having always a "next" doesn't make sense for the user (for example a "next" after entering username and password gives the focus to the username again, that can be confusing). Maybe this question of Rochana is similar to my bug reported here: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2906 I tried to override the tab index how explained in the section "How the Preferred Tab Index is Used" of https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Component.html, but nothing is changed.